# Django - Any way to update model fields on request?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using a select field to delete members of a certain model, but let's say I delete a member, and refresh the page, the member will be gone in the model but not in the page, it'll still show in the select. I know why this happens, but I want to know how to circumvent it. 
Here's my form:

```
class StudentDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {
            'name': Select(choices=[("%s" % stud['id'], "%s" % stud['name']) for stud in
                   Student.objects.all().values('id', 'name')])
    }
```

All I want is to be able to get these values from page request, and not have to restart the webserver every time. Is there any way how?

Comment: Why do you want to override the default select widget? You can pass custom `choices` to a SelectField without changing the widget. You should avoid having any code in a class body that performs a database query. That code will run every time you import the module.

Comment: How would you propose I do this then? Where would I set the choices if not on the Form body?

Comment: Have you tried passing choices to ChoiceField or a queryset to ModelChoiceField. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: I tried passing choices to a choicefield, but the problem persists. I don't get how ModelChoiceField works, since apparently my list comprehension does not work on it.

Comment: ModelChoiceField takes a queryset. If you want to pass in a list of choices, use ChoiceField. Both classes are described in detail in the docs I linked to.

Comment: ChoiceField doesn't work. The page still doesn't update on request.